# InaccessibleObjectException after upgrading Spring Boot from 2.1.9 to 2.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, javafx

My app worked perfectly before the upgrade, getting the following exception :

```
Exception in Application init method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:895)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public abstract java.lang.String com.sun.javafx.beans.IDProperty.value() accessible: module javafx.base does not "exports com.sun.javafx.beans" to unnamed module @6293abcc
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:344)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:284)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:198)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:192)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AttributeMethods.<init>(AttributeMethods.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AttributeMethods.compute(AttributeMethods.java:272)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AttributeMethods.forAnnotationType(AttributeMethods.java:255)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:467)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:439)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:210)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:227)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:227)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:227)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:227)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:227)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:194)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClass(AnnotationsScanner.java:130)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.process(AnnotationsScanner.java:107)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:97)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:78)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.scan(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:242)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.isPresent(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:98)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.isConstructorBindingType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forClass(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:300)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:57)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
at com.mdenis.mdhis3_service.core.MDHIS3_Service.init(MDHIS3_Service.java:109)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:824)
... 2 more
```

This is a Spring Boot / JavaFX project compiled using Maven.  Not even sure where to start on this one, it's a fairly large project and everything worked perfectly on 2.1.9.  I won't provide any code sample for now since i truly have no idea where this error is even coming from and the stacktrace only points to my main class which is the entry point.  Any idea where to start on this?

Comment: Maybe not the best solution, but you can try adding `--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.beans=ALL-UNNAMED` argument when launching your application.

Comment: @Slaw that indeed works!  But why do I suddenly need this?

Comment: I have no idea. Apparently Spring is trying to reflectively access a member of an annotation, `@IDProperty#value()`, but that annotation is in a package that's not exported. Why Spring wasn't doing that before I couldn't say.

Comment: I gotta say from past experience that mixing spring-boot with javafx is a bit finicky in general so I'm really not all that surprised.  Please post an answer as your solution indeed worked!

Comment: I've raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23829. If you have time to attach a sample it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much Phil, this is a pretty large project and I frankly have no idea which class the issue is coming from.  What exactly would you like me to attach?

Comment: @fabian indeed i need to look at the module system, i come from a java 7 background and i've steered away from modules so far.  i had a feeling this would be suggested.

Comment: @fabian Would the OP putting their code in an explicit module help? It seems to me the problem is Spring trying to access internals of `javafx.base`, both of which are not related to the OP's code being in a module or not. Unless you think Spring might behave differently if it was on the modulepath (and thus in a named module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix was added to Spring Framework 5.2.1 milestone which is due tomorrow.  Cheers!

Comment: I can confirm Spring Boot 2.2.1 no longer exhibits this issue!  No need for the module export parameter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue, problem was my eclipse STS was pointing to wrong JRE, my installed java and jre version was 1.8.0 where my eclipse sts was pointing to some openJDK, after correcting this. My Application started working!!